# How to make an else if and else in this If Statement

Tags: javascript

I have this if statement below. It is possible to add / make it in `if - else if - else` ?. If not tell me the reason. Thanks. Cheers

```js
var num1;
var num2 = 1;

num1 = num2 != 0  ? num2 : "";

alert(num1);
```

Comment: Easy. Use proper if/else. Anything else gets messy really quick

Comment: @FabianBettag I know I can make an easy if statement using that way. Thats why I ask if it is possible to make if - else if - else in that if statement.

Comment: Yes. It IS possible. But it's really really messy.

Comment: @FabianBettag can you show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure but our (or at least my) human brain doesn't like reading it ;-)

```
num1 = num2 != 0  
            ? num2 
              : num3 != 0  
            ? num3 
              : num4 != 0  
            ? num4 
              : num5 != 0  
            ? num5 
              : ""
```

spacing is not required just makes it more readable.

Comment: No, but as they get longer and longer they get more difficult. Then you leave it for 3 months but have to go bug hunting and you see it and weep deeply.

Comment: Seriously.  Technically correct answer that would get you lynched if you ever actually did it.  Abusing the ternary is only good for code golf and writing obfuscators.  Do not use in practice.

Comment: @AndrewBone lastly where is the else if part? :)

Comment: ':' means else and any statement that ends in a '?' is an if statement meaning anything between a ':' then a '?' is the "else if".

Comment: If you want to see how complex it can get type a long if statement in here and minify it https://javascript-minifier.com/

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to translate the ternary operator (the `? :`) into an `if else` then here goes:

```js
var num1;
var num2 = 1;

if (num2 != 0) {
  num1 = num2;
} else {
  num1 = "";
}

alert(num1);
```

Comment: that's not what i am looking for.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: In code above that I provided as sample if it is possible to make an if - else if - else statement. I don't know what is the syntax.

Comment: And I do not understand what you call an `if - else if - else` statement ^^'

Answer (score 0):

You're describing the ternary operator, and it's pretty much

```
if(part before ?) {
    (part before colon)
} else {
    (part after colon)
}
```

Like so:

```
if( num2 != 0 ) {
    num1 = num2;
} else {
    num1 = "";
}
```

In general, if you ever have anything more complicated than [a = (b==x) ? a : b], use an if block instead or risk pissing off your fellow programmers :-). Also use parens a lot to disambiguate, as order of operations can sometimes get weird...

Comment: Sure I wont piss my fellow programming. Just thinking what should it look like.